# Add an extra settings field to the Gutenberg cover block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to add an extra field to the Gutenberg cover block which lets me define a height based on a selection or dropdown.

I'm already using custom styles for the block and need an extra option for the height (which otherwise would lead to a lot of custom styles). The idea is to combine styles and height.

At the moment there is only a custom height option in the dimensions panel. See the image below.
For me, it would be a great solution if I could an extra setting there.

Is there anything like adding an extra style. I'm doing it with this code (short example):

```
    wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle(
        'core/cover',
        [
            {
                name: 'cover-custom',
                label: 'Custom',
            }
        ]
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add attributes (`Type:'string'` ans `selector : 'select'`) in your block

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/blob/master/05-recipe-card-esnext/src/index.js

Comment: I tried to understand it. But it seems, that the example is an own block type. Right?